# Parsing block comments with javacc

Tags: java, parsing, lexical-analysis, javacc

I'm trying to write some javacc grammar to parse a file that contains multi-line comments, for example, the following are all valid:

```
/**/
/* */
/* This is a comment */
/* This
   is
   a
   multiline
   comment
*/
```

I would like the parsing to fail if there is a `/*` not closed by a `*/`, or a closing `*/` without an opening `/*`.

I'm not trying to skip the comments, I want the comments available as tokens.

So far I have tried this method, which works but will not fail on un-closed `/*`:

```
options {
  STATIC = false;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(BlockComments)

package com.company;

public class BlockComments {}

PARSER_END(BlockComments)

TOKEN : { < START_BLOCK_COMMENT : "/*" >  : WITHIN_BLOCK_COMMENT }
<WITHIN_BLOCK_COMMENT> TOKEN: { < BLOCK_COMMENT: (~["*", "/"] | "*" ~["/"])+ > }
<WITHIN_BLOCK_COMMENT> TOKEN: { < END_BLOCK_COMMENT: "*/" > : DEFAULT }

SKIP : {
  "\n"
}
```

The other option I have tried is this, which has the same problem and the slight difference that `/*` and `*/` are skipped instead being read as tokens:

```
options {
  STATIC = false;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(BlockComments)

package com.company;

public class BlockComments {}

PARSER_END(BlockComments)

SKIP : { "/*" : WITHIN_BLOCK_COMMENT }
<WITHIN_BLOCK_COMMENT> TOKEN: { <BLOCK_COMMENT: (~["*", "/"] | "*" ~["/"])+ > }
<WITHIN_BLOCK_COMMENT> SKIP : { "*/" : DEFAULT }

SKIP : {
  "\n"
}
```

I tried using `MORE : { "/*" : WITHIN_BLOCK_COMMENT }` in the second option which makes sure parsing fails for un-closed `/*`, but it makes all of the `BLOCK_COMMENT` tokens start with `/*` which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the rest of your file looks like, so I'll assume that a file is expected to be a sequence of comments preceded, followed, and separated by zero or more spaces and newlines.

What I would do is this:

```
TOKEN : { < BLOCK_COMMENT_START : "/*" >  : WITHIN_BLOCK_COMMENT }
<WITHIN_BLOCK_COMMENT> TOKEN: { <CHAR_IN_COMMENT: ~[] > }
<WITHIN_BLOCK_COMMENT> TOKEN: { < END_BLOCK_COMMENT: "*/" > : DEFAULT }

SKIP : {
  "\n" | " " 
}
```

Now in the parser we have

```
void start() : {String s ; } {
    (
        s = comment()  {System.out.println(s); }
    )*
}

String comment() :
{   Token t ;
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer() ;
}
{  <START_BLOCK_COMMENT>
   (
         t=<CHAR_IN_COMMENT>  {b.append( t.image ) ; }
   )*
   <END_BLOCK_COMMENT>
   {return b.toString() ; }
}
```

Now you don't get a lexical error for a missing `*/`, but you do get a parse exception.